# Check if one of multiple values is present in a column

Tags: vba, excel, text, excel-formula

I have a table in Excel 2013 that has has thousands of records of food items (Beef-frozen, beef-chilled, beef-brisket, beef-ribs, chicken-fillet, chicken-whole, fish-skinned, fish-whole, yogurt, lettuce-imported, lettuce-frozen, tomato-fresh,tomato, water, milk,...etc) stored in column A. Notice the value may contain other content than the food item name.

I created column B next to column A. I want column B to hold the category of the food item in column A. For example, if A1 has in it "Beef" or "Chicken" or "Fish" then B1 should equal "Meat". If A1 has in it "Tomato" or "Lettuce" or "Onion" then B1 should equal "Vegetable".

What is the best way to achieve it?

Comment: You could create an array that holds the values such as Beef, Chicken, or Fish and then compare each cell using the InStr function (look up the documentation) while looping through the array. Then have an if statement that places meat or vegetable in the corresponding cell.

Comment: @ExcelHero typed before thinking.  will delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have column headers, enter this formula in cell B2:

```
=REPT("Meat",MAX(IFERROR(MATCH({"*beef*","*chicken*","*fish*"},A2,),)))    &    REPT("Vegetable",MAX(IFERROR(MATCH({"*tomato*","*lettuce*","*onion*"},A2,),)))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now copy B2 and select B3 down as far as you need and paste.

Note: please look closely at the big gap in the middle of the formula. You'll see that this is really two separate formulas concatenated together with an ampersand. You can easily extend this formula in the same way by adding another phrase similar to the first two for a new category. In fact, you could add many more categories in this fashion.

Comment: Pretty clever Daniel! I would of never thought to use the REPT function this way.

Comment: Thanks man. That was very helpful and easy to use. There needs to be a Nobel prize for Excel!!

Answer (score 0):

Set up a two column table.  Name it, for example `FoodTable`.  Have the first column Named `Word` (for keyword) and the second column `Type`, for the type of product.  Something like this:

[image]

Then, with your data in column A, enter the following formula in B1 and fill down:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER(FIND(FoodTable[Word],A1)),FoodTable[Type])
```

Results:

[image]